# Quotation marks are not appearing adequately

Tags: punctuation

In certain documents of mine, the quotation marks are displayed incorrectly. For instance, while writing down `word', as usual, the word is formatted within two reverse backticks.

Some of my other files do not display the same problem. I generally recycle my headers. I've tried in a process of elimination to locate which part of the header is responsible for this state of affairs but so far, have not been successful. My headers are becoming more and more messy and cluttered, many times with packages and styles that are not even called by the document.

I hereby present one header of a document that is rendering this problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}             
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, minimum size=2em]
\tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxright}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{128}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Max}{Max}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\def\Vox{$^{\fbox {\/}}$}
\def\dalem{\mbox{\Vox}}
\def\prom{
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[prop]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[prop]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{exa}[prop]{Example}
\newtheorem{sch}[prop]{Scholium}
\newtheorem{rem}[prop]{Remark}
\newtheorem{axi}[prop]{Axiom System}
\newtheorem{con}[prop]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{theor}[prop]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cla}[prop]{Claim}
\newtheorem{hypo}[prop]{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{tef}[prop]{Definition}}

\pagestyle {myheadings}

\prom

\tikzset
{
box/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, very thick, text width=7.5em, minimum height=2em,text centered},
}

\title{XXX}
\author{XXX}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
```

Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Judging from your document header, I'd say there's probably an interaction between the `csquotes`, `txfonts` and `mathpazo` packages. (Incidentally, why do you load both `txfonts` and `mathpazo`?) It's not possible to verify this conjecture, though, as you don't provide a code snippet that actually generates the problem behavior you're trying to fix.

Comment: It would be good if you could trim everything from your example document that doesn't have anything to do with the problem (all the `\newtheorem` definitions, the `lettrine` package`, the `\tikzset`, for example) and make sure that the document is compilable (needs an `\end{document}`), and that it actually demonstrates the problem (you haven't used quotes anywhere). Then you have a minimal working example document, which makes it much easier for others to help in finding the problem.

Comment: The quotes you get are the normal ones in the Palatino font that you ask for with `\usepackage{mathpazo}`. There's nothing strange about them: it's just how they've been designed by Hermann Zapf (Palatino's author)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `mathpazo` package and including `babel` with USenglish, I've got the result desired with no errors or warnings.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}             
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, minimum size=2em]
\tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxright}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{128}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Max}{Max}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\def\Vox{$^{\fbox {\/}}$}
\def\dalem{\mbox{\Vox}}
\def\prom{
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[prop]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[prop]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{exa}[prop]{Example}
\newtheorem{sch}[prop]{Scholium}
\newtheorem{rem}[prop]{Remark}
\newtheorem{axi}[prop]{Axiom System}
\newtheorem{con}[prop]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{theor}[prop]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cla}[prop]{Claim}
\newtheorem{hypo}[prop]{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{tef}[prop]{Definition}}

\pagestyle {myheadings}

\prom

\tikzset
{
box/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, very thick, text width=7.5em, minimum height=2em,text centered},
}

\title{XXX}
\author{XXX}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

    Do not be alarmed. This is a `kindness'.
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot from document]

Comment: I am writing a paper for a journal with its own latex format. They refuse all my attempts to get decent quotation signs! None of the remedies shown on this page help. Whatever I try, I get  ugly quotation signs, with right-slanted apostrophes both at the beginning and the end. I want my 66 and 99 back! Can I overrule the bad taste of the designer without getting into trouble with my editor?